# how to get the file name from end

Tags: php

I have different strings but all the stings end with a doc or pdf file
C:\profiles\gim.doc
C:\doc\myprofile\profile.pdf

I want to get the file names from the path.
Whats the fastest way to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`basename()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
echo basename("C:\doc\myprofile\profile.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the filename without the extension...

```
echo pathinfo('C:\doc\myprofile\profile.pdf', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with argument **PHP_URL_PATH**

eg:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: How does this get the filename part from the strings?

Comment: @JohnP value of `[path]`  is the filename..isn't it??

Comment: @JohnP after getting the filename he can extract filename , there are a lot of functions to do so...

Comment: But he doesn't need to extract the filepaths at all. They are available as strings. The OP has already got the filename strings.